# Reading and writing a variable slice of the array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

As we all know, we can easily extract data from arrays using slicing:

```
>>> L = range(10)
>>> L[::2]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

I often write a code when I need to use slicing as follows:

```
>>> L[ind:ind+x]
```

What I am curious now is: why there is no single operator to achieve that? For example in Verilog we could use slicing like:

```
>>> L[ind+:x]
```

Is there any other way to easily achieve that functionality?

Answer (score 2):

> why there is no single operator to achieve that?

The syntax for list slicing hasn't changed since early versions of Python. The *reason* may be due to the judgement of an individual or influences from other languages. It is what it is. We must learn to live with it.

> Is there any other way to easily achieve that functionality?

Well, sure. Note `[]` is syntactic sugar for `__getitem__` and `ind:ind+x` can be represented as a `slice` object. Perhaps you prefer the second variation?

```
L = list(range(10))

L[3:7]                        # [3, 4, 5, 6]

m, k = 3, 4
L.__getitem__(slice(m, m+k))  # [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Python does not have such a syntax.  That's OK though--Python is not a language that prizes having ten ways to do everything.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such syntax. The only thing to programmatically manipulate slicing is `slice` objects.

```
i = slice(ind, ind+x)
print(x[i])
```